# Not getting the values of columns in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

-1

I have a text file abc.txt in which there are n number of columns I want to extract only column number 5 whose heading is senddata I am using the below command for that:-

```
awk -F "(|~|)" '{ print  $5 }' /opt/var/acb.txt
```

I am using the above command to extract column 5 from file abc.txt in which I am getting the complete column values but not the heading of the column.

the file abc.txt has data as follows :-

```
prodid|~|prodtype|~|creationtime|~|affirmcode|~|senddata|~|city|~|country
334|~|T|~|4:09|~|BC334|~|Y|~|KG|~|ABC
443|~|F|~|4:44|~|RT548|~|Y|~|FR|~|FR
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Please format your code and data properly. Use the `{}` in your editor or prepend them with 4 spaces.

Comment: the code is properly formatted i think

Comment: Isn't that better, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `|` has special meaning in regular expressions you have to [escape](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html) it if you want literal `|`. Let `file.txt` content be

```
prodid|~|prodtype|~|creationtime|~|affirmcode|~|senddata|~|city|~|country
334|~|T|~|4:09|~|BC334|~|Y|~|KG|~|ABC
443|~|F|~|4:44|~|RT548|~|Y|~|FR|~|FR
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\|~\\|"}{print $5}' file.txt
```

output

```
senddata
Y
Y
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: IMHO if you're at the point of doubling up escapes you're better off for clarity using a bracket expression, e.g. `[|]` instead of `\\|`.

Answer (score 4):

The pipe character is special for regular expressions. A multi-character FS is treated as a regular expression. Try

```sh
awk -F '[|]~[|]' ...
```